# Error trying to pass MatrixViewProjection to shader: "must have class/struct/union"

Tags: opengl, matrix, transform, shader

I'm getting this error while trying to learning some of opengl and shaders stuff...

the code:

```
#pragma once

#include "OpenGL.h"
#include "glm\glm.hpp"
#include "glm\gtx\transform.hpp"
#include "Camera.h"




class Transform
{


private:

glm::vec3 position;     
glm::vec3 rotation;
glm::vec3 scale;


public:
Transform(void);
~Transform(void);


inline glm::vec3* GetPos() { return &position; }
inline glm::vec3* GetRot() { return &rotation; }
inline glm::vec3* GetScale() { return &scale; }
inline void SetPos(glm::vec3& pos) { this->position = pos; }
inline void SetRot(glm::vec3& rot) { this->rotation = rot; }
inline void SetScale(glm::vec3& scale) { this->scale = scale; }


void Update();


/*inline glm::mat4 GetModelMatrix() const
{
    glm::mat4 posMat = glm::translate(position);
    glm::mat4 scaleMat = glm::scale(scale);
    glm::mat4 rotX = glm::rotate(rotation.x, glm::vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0));
    glm::mat4 rotY = glm::rotate(rotation.y, glm::vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0));
    glm::mat4 rotZ = glm::rotate(rotation.z, glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0));
    glm::mat4 rotMat = rotX * rotY * rotZ;
    return posMat * rotMat * scaleMat; //Model Matrix
}
*/
//glm::mat4 GetMVP();



inline glm::mat4 GetMVP(Camera& camera)  //LINE A
{
    glm::mat4 posMat = glm::translate(position);
    glm::mat4 scaleMat = glm::scale(scale);
    glm::mat4 rotX = glm::rotate(rotation.x, glm::vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0));
    glm::mat4 rotY = glm::rotate(rotation.y, glm::vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0));
    glm::mat4 rotZ = glm::rotate(rotation.z, glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0));
    glm::mat4 rotMat = rotX * rotY * rotZ;
    glm::mat4 ModelMatrix = posMat * rotMat * scaleMat;


    glm::mat4 MVP = camera.GetViewProjection()* ModelMatrix; //LINE B
    return MVP;
}



};
```

this code is part of a function of the class Transform.

I'm getting errors in line A and B

The Errors:

```
error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'Camera'
error C2065: 'camera' : undeclared identifier
error C2228: left of '.GetViewProjection' must have class/struct/union
```

the third error is the relevant (line B)

what can it be the cause?
"must have class/struct/union" ?

### ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Edited Camera.h

```
#include "OpenGL.h"
#include "Input.h"
#include "Input_Keys.h"
#include "Transform.h"

class Camera 
{
glm::mat4 projection;
glm::vec3 pos;
glm::vec3 forward;
glm::vec3 up;

//para rot vertical
glm::vec3 right;


float FOV;
float moveSpeed;
bool freeze;

float rot_horizontal;
float rot_vertical;

Input* input_handler;
Window* window_handler;
public:

Camera(bool _freeze ,float _moveSpeed , const glm::vec3& pos, float fov, float aspect, float zNear, float zFar);
~Camera(void);

void SetInputHandler(Input* _input);

void SetFreeze(bool freeze);

void Move(); //WASD
void Look(); //up down left right

void ShowData();

glm::mat4 Camera:: GetViewProjection();




};
```

and GetViewProjection ...

```
glm::mat4 Camera:: GetViewProjection()
{
    return projection * glm::lookAt(pos, pos + forward, up);
}
```

### ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

### Edited

---

OK, now there is only one error:

```
error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'Camera'
```

I've noticed that the getviewprojection() has the "Camera::"so I delete it, and made the inline function into a non-inline function

in Transform class ...

```
#pragma once

#include "OpenGL.h"
#include "glm\glm.hpp"
#include "glm\gtx\transform.hpp"
#include "Camera.h"
```

in Camera class...

```
#pragma once

#include "OpenGL.h"
#include "Input.h"
#include "Input_Keys.h"
#include "Transform.h"
```

I think the order should matter.. or not?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the header which contains the definition of the `Camera` class in this file. Near the top you should do something like:

```
#include "Camera.h" // Or whatever the name of the header that contains the Camera definition is
```

Comment: I did it , that's why it's strange

Comment: Can you post the contents of that file, and the line used to include it? It could be that the definition is getting omitted due to a `#define`, or something else. But the compiler is telling you that it doesn't know what a `Camera` is for some reason.

Comment: ^^  the part that bothers me is the "must have class/struct/union"